# Why does this RTTI optimization make things slower?

Tags: delphi, optimization, rtti

I've got an operation that's being called repeatedly in a loop. With a TRttiField:

```
if (field.name = '') or (field.Name[1] <> 'F') then
  continue;
```

Profiling shows that I'm spending a lot of time in UStrAsg and UStrClr because of this.  Field.Name has to make a virtual call to TRttiInstanceFieldEx.GetName, which has to perform a UTF8-to-string conversion on the underlying RTTI structure's name.  This is happening twice per loop iteration.

I tried to cut all that out by bypassing the string conversions:

```
handle := PFieldExEntry(field.Handle);
if (handle.name = '') or (handle.Name[1] <> 'F') then
      continue;
```

I expected to see about a 5% speed gain from this.  Instead, the loop takes several seconds longer to execute, approximately 20-25% slower!  I checked the generated ASM to make sure it wasn't doing anything screwy like making string copies from the RTTI structures to the local stack, but it isn't.  I can't see any reason why this should have gotten slower.  Anyone have any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: No, but have you tried just storing the name rather than retrieving it twice? That's the most obvious optimisation that you seem to have missed.

Comment: @Moz: I tried that. It helps a little.  I figured this would help more, though.

Comment: What happens if you copy handle.Name into a temp and use that in the "if"?

Comment: Why guess? Just pause it, or you could even just single-step it at the assembly language level. Since it's so much slower you won't have any trouble seeing what it's doing.

Comment: Can you show us the disassembled ASM you see for the code above?

Comment: @Mike: I *can* see what it's doing at the ASM level, and the new version is incredibly simple and quite short. If there was any obvious reason for this, I wouldn't be asking on here.

Comment: @Mason: Well, I'm sure you can see the ASM. Did you actually either a)step through the whole thing in ASM, not skipping over any calls but going all the way down and back, or b) assuming that would take too long, loop it long enough to take stackshots and examine them? If something I didn't think of is going on, that finds it.

Comment: @Mike: Are you actually familiar with Delphi and its RTTI model?  You shouldn't need to be able to see the ASM to tell from the code I posted that there are no calls being made at all; just dereferencing pointers into records (structs) in memory and reading from their members. The previous version *did* have a call chain at least 3 levels deep, but I replaced it with one with no calls. That's why it doesn't make sense that it got slower.

Comment: @Mason: Well then, the time is going somewhere you didn't think of. At bottom it's a computer. I've heard people say "I don't know why it's slow, but I know I don't need to look." Suit yourself.

Comment: What does profiling has to say about your second variant?

Answer (score 1):

The field your new code reads is declared as a ShortString. As of Delphi 5, the compiler converts ShortStrings to long strings before generating the code for most string operations. (At least, that's the way it was with non-Unicode Delphi. Maybe Unicode Delphi restores some ShortString-related optimizations.)

Whereas the TRttiField wrapper might take advantage of the knowledge that it's populating a UTF-8 string with data that's already occupying one byte per character, I'd expect the ShortString-to-string code that your new loop employs might use a more general-purpose conversion routine, and you're paying the price for generality.

You might try foregoing string-conversion operations entirely. Instead, get a pointer to the first byte:

```
handle := PFieldExEntry(field.Handle);
NameP := PAnsiChar(@handle.name);
if (NameP[0] = #0) or (NameP[1] <> 'F') then
  continue;
```

Note that although it's declared as a ShortString, it's not *really* one. It doesnn't really occupy 256 bytes. Instead, it occupies the minimum amount of memory required to hold its length byte and its characters.

Comment: Nope.  As I said in the original post, I checked the ASM to make sure it wasn't doing anything stupid like string conversions, and it's not.  It's looking directly at the data structures.

Comment: It is a PShortstring, not a PAnsiChar. Name[0] is the length, and text starts at Name[1] with no trimming #0 character. With a PAnsiChar, the text starts at Name[0] and finishes with a #0 character.

Comment: I know, @A.Bouchez. My code reflects that. Mason's first test is that the string is empty; when the string is empty, the length byte in `Name[0]` is zero. The point of my code was to *not* treat the value as a ShortString. The type-cast to PAnsiChar is to allow array indexing and to keep the second test readable. I could have used `PByteArray` instead, and then written `(NameP[0] = 0) or (NameP[1] <> Ord('F'))` instead.

Comment: AFAIK, the compiler does NOT convert shortstring to string if you just check (handle.name = '') or (handle.Name[1] <> 'F') - it will convert only if it's used in a function/procedure which needs a string parameter. So your code is not faster, it only obfuscates the shortstring type. You should have written: NameP := PShortString(@handle.name); if (NameP[0]=#0) or (NameP[1]<>'F') then continue; It's incorrect to typecast a PShortString into a PAnsiChar. PAnsiChar is not just an array of char: it expects an ending #0. Use step by step debugging and look at your NameP variable content...

Comment: If I'd written that, @A.Bouchez, it would have been a syntax error because it would attempt to reference a PShortString as though it were an array. Under my assumption that the compiler converts ShortStrings to long strings, it would be pointless to use any ShortString-related type. That's why I used PAnsiChar, which *can* represent a pointer to a null-terminated array of characters, but can equally well represent a pointer to *any* AnsiChar, or even any byte that can be *treated as* an AnsiChar.